# Merging multiple form libraries into a single view

Tags: infopath, filter, form, form-library, merge

I currently have two separate form libraries: one old one, and one new one. All new forms go into the new one, but the old library still has active forms in it. We created a page with filtered views from both libraries that only show forms created by the active user.

This is a workable solution, however, now we look to add a new form library for even newer forms. This "status" view will now contain three different library views in one, filtered to the active user.

While this will still be "usable," it's not very pretty.

Is there a way to merge the filtered forms from these different form libraries into a single library view?

Comment: Quick answer, Yes. You'll need to write code though.

Comment: Why not add these forms into existing libraries as new content types?

Comment: Thanks @jpollar. Unfortunately, I don't have the tools needed to write code, as much as I'd love to.

Comment: @EricAlexander Could you elaborate on that? This can be done while still keeping the different form versions separate?